# How to have multiple colored light sources

Tags: modeling, objects

I’ve been experimenting with the quick effects especially quick smoke. But I want to have to colored light sources from different angles ie. red and blue but they always blend together and make one color. How can I fix it?

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you mean - an image of the results you're getting and description of what is not right would be helpful. And don't forget to mention what render engine (Cycles, Blender Render, ...) you are using. I can only guess that you've added two light sources and set them each to a different color but the 'smoke' is being equally lit by both...? Sounds like you possibly need to increase the smoke density.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project. Add images that might help us understand your scene

Answer (score 2):

1. Add cube( or whatever you want your smoke to be emitted from).
2. Select theis Object, press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> an enter "Quick smoke". Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to start the simulation.
3. Add two simple planes and position them where you want your light to come from.
4. Give each plane a material (two different materials, they should not share one material)
5. Press "use nodes" in the material settings and change the default "diffuse" shader to "Emission"
6. Choose a color for each material
7. Ramp up the strength (depending on the size of your planes and the distance to the smoke

You can see the result and the "node setup" in the screenshot.

I hope this answers your question. 
[image]